# How to display an object's data on client side using json?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

```
  public class ProductController : ApiController
     {
    Product[] products = new Product[] 
       { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
        };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public string GetProductById(int id)
    {
        Product product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        //var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(product);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
        return json;
        //return product;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
    {
        return products.Where(
            (p) => string.Equals(p.Category, category,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Following code is being used in the consumer application. I am getting an undefined data at the client side but when list is passed which is already in json format  gets displayed. But when it comes to object details being displayed it passing character by character if returned as  a serialized string.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WEbAPIConsumer._Default" %>

   <asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent"     ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          alert("hello");          
            function getProducts() {
               $.getJSON("http://localhost:51641/api/product/1",
                function (data) {
                    $('#products').empty(); // Clear the table body.
                    // Loop through the list of products.
                    //alert(data);
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        // Add a table row for the product.
                        alert(val.Name);
                        var row = '<td>' + val.Name + '</td><td>' +   val.Price + '</td>';
                        $('<tr/>', { html: row })  // Append the name.
                            .appendTo($('#products'));
                    });
                });
        }
        $(document).ready(getProducts);
    });
</script>

</asp:Content>
       <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>Products</h2>
   <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="products">
    </tbody>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
   $.each(data,function(idx, obj) {
                            // Add a table row for the product.
                            alert(obj.Name);
                            var row = '<td>' + obj.Name + '</td><td>' +   obj.Price + '</td>';
                            $('<tr/>', { html: row })  // Append the name.
                                .appendTo($('#products'));
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

parse the data into json if it is coming as json string.

```
data=$.parseJSON(data);//this line parses the data into json
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    // Add a table row for the product.
                    alert(val.Name);
                    var row = '<td>' + val.Name + '</td><td>' +   val.Price + '</td>';
                    $('<tr/>', { html: row })  // Append the name.
                        .appendTo($('#products'));
                });
```